# Flyout menu using JQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi guys I am trying to create a fly-out menu here. The idea is to float the menu from left to the right. What I did is I created two unordered lists one for the icons and and one for the menu itself. Here is my HTML code.

```
<ul class="icon-menu">
            <li class="icon-box home"> 
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="icon home"></span>

                </a>
            </li>   


            <li class="icon-box aboutme"> 
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="icon aboutme"></span>

                </a>
            </li>


            <li class="icon-box portfolio"> 
                 <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon portfolio"></span>

                 </a>
            </li>


            <li class="icon-box blog"> 
                 <a href="#">
                     <span class="icon blog"></span>

                 </a>
            </li>


            <li class="icon-box contact"> 
                 <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon contact"></span>
                   </a>
            </li>



      </ul>
```

And Here is my CSS code:

```
    body { background: #263544; }

ul.icon-menu { margin-top:20px; }
li.icon-box { width: 120px; height: 120px; list-style: none; left: -47px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 4px; }
li.icon-box.home { background: #e74c3c; }
li.icon-box.aboutme { background: #1dd0ad; }
li.icon-box.portfolio { background: #3498db; }
li.icon-box.blog { background: #f1c40f; }
li.icon-box.contact { background: #f39c12; }

span.icon { display: inline-block; background: url('img/icon-sprites.png')no-repeat;  width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 44px 40px;}
span.icon.home { background-position: 0px 0px;}
span.icon.aboutme { background-position: -36px 0px;}
span.icon.portfolio { background-position: -72px 0px;}
span.icon.blog { background-position: -109px 0px;}
span.icon.contact { background-position: -145px 0px;}


ul.menu { margin-top:20px; position: absolute;  }
li.menu-box { width: 120px; height: 120px; list-style: none; left: -47px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 4px; }
li.menu-box.home { background: #e74c3c; }
li.menu-box.aboutme { background: #1dd0ad; }
li.menu-box.portfolio { background: #3498db; }
li.menu-box.blog { background: #f1c40f; }
li.menu-box.contact { background: #f39c12; }

a{ text-decoration: none; }
h2 {  color: #fff; font-size: 22px; margin: 0 24px;}
```

Here is the image I am trying to workout using jQuery.

[image]

First my problem is I can't put them together at once and I dont know how to formulate the jQuery effect. So the idea is to whenever I hover my mouse to a menu icon box it will show up the hide menu box.

Here is the JSfiddle LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/2Y5Zm/

Comment: why `jquery` ? i mean you can do it by using `css` too. 
just by using `:hover` state for `<a>` elements in your css.

Comment: @VedantTerkar jQuery could add browser compatibility and probably more effects.

Comment: @Minister yeah. that's true.
but according to op's question i think here need of `jquery` is very less

Comment: Is this a "Do it for me" question or have you already tried some `jQuery` on this?

Comment: @Minister Well that is the Question. What does he want? There are many things you can do with css only. :)

Comment: @VedantTerkar The questions of new members usually contain partial information, but yes - you are right - the OP should be more precise. This is why +1 for MikaldL. :-)

Comment: @MikaldL i agree with you. +1 from me too :)..

Comment: Hi guys sorry if my statement above is incomplete will post my JQuery code later on. But if possible you can also share your ideas to do this using JQuery or CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y5Zm/2/)

I've modified your example (only home block). Here is what you can achieve with css only.

```
.icon-box a { display: block; }
.icon-box h2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 0; background: #E74C3C; line-height: 120px; width: 120px; -webkit-transition: all  .3s;
-moz-transition: all .5s;
-ms-transition: all .5s;
-o-transition: all .5s;
transition: all .5s;}
.icon-box a:hover h2 { opacity: 1; left: 120px; margin: 0;
text-align: center;
border-left: 2px solid #8D0F0F;}
```

And the changes in the html structure:

```
               <li class="icon-box home"> 
                    <a href="#">
                      <span class="icon home"></span>
                      <h2>Home</h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

I've add `h2` inside the list.

Comment: I really like your idea. Is it also possible to make the Home H2 box stayed on the screen whenever I hover on it? Cause right now its dissapearing.

Comment: Last Chrome: works fine when hovering on it. <h2> is inside <a>, so it will allways stay visible when hovering on <a>

Answer (score 0):

I would take a completely different approach to this. I would make a div that holds each line of the fly-out options. This div would be the initial size with overflow:hidden. Then i would put all the fly-out options inside this div with float-left, the first being the initial picture to show.

Then use Jquery to animate the fly-out on a mouse-over or click. The new width of the holder div should be:

> amount_options_this_flyout_holds * flyout_options_div_width.

(sorry for incorrectness, doing this out of my head)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.holder').click(function(){
        var newWidth = $('.option', this).length * 'option_width'; //gets the amount of option and multiplies.
        $(this).css('width', newWidth);
    });
]);
```

With some fiddling you should get this to work properly. Your base css for the holder should be the initial width. And you need to add functionality in that JQuery script to animate it back. With .animate you can put in some easing animation for extra bonus points.

*I will edit this later with some .animate code.

Comment: Hi I like your thoughts. Is it possible to show me the whole process for this using jsfiddle?

Comment: I'll see what i can do but i'm very busy at work atm. What you basicaly do is just change the width of the div that holds everything with javascript. Since you have that holder div on overflow:hidden it will not show anything outside it's original size until it gets expanded by a fly over, mouse click or whatever. That is all to it, nothing complicated.